# Iterable Unpacking Evaluation Order

Tags: python, variable-assignment, iterable-unpacking

I recently answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47841934/making-an-undo-function-for-a-7x7-board-in-python/47841954#47841954) where a user was having trouble because they were appending a multi-dimensional array to another array, and it was brought to my attention in my answer that it is possible to use iterable unpacking to populate an `x` and `y` value and assign to `board[x][y]` on the same line.

I had expected this to throw an error as `x` and `y` had at the time not been defined, as, even in the `iterable-unpacking` tag it reads:

> elements of an iterable are **simultaneously** assigned to multiple values

This can be seen as working in the following example:

```
>>> board = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
>>> move = [0, 1, 2]
>>> x, y, board[x][y] = move
>>> board
[[0, 2], [0, 0]]
```

Which is the same as:

```
>>> board = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
>>> move = [0, 1, 2]
>>> x = move[0]
>>> y = move[1]
>>> board[x][y] = move[2]
>>> board
[[0, 2], [0, 0]]
```

And yet when calculating the Fibonacci sequence using:

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

It doesn't evaluate as:

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

And when swapping values with:

```
a, b = b, a
```

It doesn't evaluate as:

```
a = b
b = a
```

So why does this work in the first example?

Comment: These examples don't seem to be equivalent.  I mean, in the first example, you have `<some variables> = <some constant values>`. The second examples tries to involve the same variables on both sides of the `=`.

Comment: I think using "Asynchronous" in the title is a bit off the topic of the question and may lead people searching for python `async` in the wrong direction. perhaps something more like "Iterable unpacking evaluation order"?

Comment: @Aaron Thanks, I couldn't come up with a better term so I just googled the opposite of simultaneous, I'll change it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right side of the `=` is always evaluated first, in this case it is packing a tuple. That tuple is then unpacked when interpreting the left hand side. The left and right sides do not share knowledge of variables. The RHS becomes a value and then the LHS uses that *value* to assign to the variables (labels).

In your example the values of `x` and `y` are determined after the RHS is evaluated. The unpacking then occurs left to right, so that `board[x][y]` has valid indices.

Switching the order demonstrates the unpacking sequence:

```
>>> board[x][y], x, y = move[2], move[0], move[1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a984ef3168f8> in <module>()
----> 1 board[x][y], x, y = move[2], move[0], move[1]    
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: While I find it unlikely to change, is this stated anywhere to be intended behavior, or is it simply an implementation detail? I can see potential future situations where automated parallelization may break this (again, unlikely but possible).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=unpacking%20tuples       

 "Although the definition of assignment implies that overlaps between the left-hand side and the right-hand side are ‘simultaneous’ (for example a, b = b, a swaps two variables), overlaps within the collection of assigned-to variables occur left-to-right, sometimes resulting in confusion. For instance, the following program prints [0, 2]:

x = [0, 1]
i = 0
i, x[i] = 1, 2         # i is updated, then x[i] is updated
print(x)